# Something strange with Firefox and fixed position via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a website and I'm using jQuery and the CSS framework [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). This framework changes actually every CSS default property of every object on the page, so it's quite hard to get if this is a CSS problem.

I have this code:

```
function handleNavBarDot() {
    var $navbar = $('nav#nav-bar'),
        $win = $(window);

    // inserting the div#circle after the nav bar in the markup
    $navbar.after('<div id="circle"></div>');
    var $dot = $('div#circle');

    function attachDot() {
        // using + (and not -) because the margin is negative
        var topStart = parseDim($navbar.css('top')) + parseDim($navbar.css('margin-top'));
        var availHeight = $navbar.outerHeight();
        var pageScrolled = $win.scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $win.height());

        $dot.css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'right': (parseDim($navbar.css('right')) - Math.floor($dot.width() / 2)) + 'px',
            'top': (topStart + availHeight * pageScrolled) + 'px',
        });
    }

    attachDot();
    $win.resize(attachDot);
    $win.scroll(attachDot);
}
```

which moves this little dot up and down a vertical line near the navigation bar. As you can see, the vertical offset is calculated based on how much page has been scrolled down; the horizontal position is calculated based on the position of the navigation bar, which is also set by jQuery in another part of the script (in order to make it always fixed to the side of the page content - which has fixed width - instead of fixed to the browser window).

When I run this in Chrome/Safari/Opera everything works fine and the dot is always in the right position.
In Firefox though, the dot is where it should be only when I first load the page. After a single call to `$(window).scroll()` or to `$(window).resize()` the dot moves to the right, altering its `right` CSS property.
When I inspect the page, the `element.style` `right` property changes on resize and scroll and it's of the right value, but the computed `right` is different - a little moved on the right.

Final note: in Firebug, if I disable/re-enable the

```
*, *:after, *:before { -moz-box-sizing: border-box }
```

the dot comes back to the right position.

What can be the cause of this problem?

(if you want to see the problem in action, head to [the actual site](http://www.studiolegaleleopardi.it/tmp/))

Comment: Looks like a browser bug to me. Also, not really on the topic: browsers fire "scroll" events very, very often. You may want to include a timer mechanism so that you can avoid doing DOM manipulations on every "scoll" event, and only do them at most once every 100ms or so.

Comment: @Pointy Yep, to me too. I still couldn't try it on IE though.

Comment: @Pointy the optimization with timers is the next stage of development, I'm trying to work this out first.

Comment: For me, it always seems to be 15px wrong. Also it magically fixes itself when the window loses focus. It's like the browser gets confused about the window geometry or something.

Comment: @Pointy nope, if my window loses focus the dot stays in its original wrong position. So in your Firefox (on what OS?) it's shifted from the navbar even when you just loaded the page and didn't scroll/resize?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 20 on Linux. When I bring up the Firebug window (separate window), moving the mouse out of the main window over the firebug window makes the dot snap back to the right position. Interestingly, Firebug accurately reports the changing position in the "Layout" view.

Comment: @Pointy it has to be a browser bug, because it does that whatever `right` attribute I set. That's gonna be tough to solve...